# Use query parameters defined in URL for filtering a resource from a RESTful API with node/express?

Tags: node.js, express

How can I do this type of thing on node/express

```
app.get("/users/:id/state/:state", (req, res) => {
      if (req.params.state== 'Published') {
            //do somehting
      } else {
            //do something
      }
});
```

but filtering by state?
Exampe, I wanna have this type of route `/users/123/posts?state=published`,
how do I have to hendle it on node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In express, URL query strings do not need to be specified in the route. Instead, you access them using `req.query`:

```
app.get("/users/:id/posts", (req, res) => {
    if (req.query.state  == 'published') {
      console.log("published");
    } else {
      console.log("not published");
    }
});
```

This will process the url: `/users/123/posts?state=published`